# How to set vector symbol outline properties in pyqgis 3?

Tags: symbology, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a polygon vector layer and I want to style it within a processing script. Part of the code creates a categorized symbology for my layer but I cannot find a reference online on how to access the properties of the stroke/border. I have checked the documentation [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbol.html) and I can only find `setColor` and `setOpacity` functions which I have used.

```
    scenarios = {}
    for i, fld in enumerate(fld_names):
        #attribute_value = (color, label)
        scenarios[fld] = (colors[i%2], fld)

    categories = []
    for attr, (color,label) in scenarios.items():
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(lyr.geometryType())
        symbol.setColor(QtGui.QColor(color))
        #symbol.setOpacity(0.5)
        category = QgsRendererCategory(attr, symbol, label)
        categories.append(category)

    renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('SCENARIO', categories)
    lyr.setRenderer(renderer)
    lyr.setOpacity(.5)
    lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setStrokeColor()` method is found in the [QgsSymbolLayer](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbolLayer.html#a9515fc451624adcf1481229eb1873935) properties which in your case would be added by using:

```
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeColor(QColor(color))
```

Comment: @strythe - Most welcome, glad it helped :)